# Sql Server large database use and query: How to deal with them?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, sql-server-2014

I read a few articles and thread in this community about large db mainteinance and best practices. However, I could not avoid mine to collapse.

I need to manage a new db where the biggest table countains approximately 300 Millions records.

Server machine: windows server 2012, 2.4 ghz, 40 gb ram, SQL SERVER Standard.

I created the database in SSMS 14, imported all the data in the 4 different tables through a SSIS package. The db was really big. Even really simple queries took definitely too long time to execute. I needed to create joins between those huge tables in order to obtain one final table. The views just did not worked out (errors in selecting the data in the view listed later), and joins failed always, after some hours.

Errors came out after some executing:

- "out of memory"
- the log file was definitely enlarging too much during queries execution (more than 200 GB)  and was completely covering the whole server disk space. -> "log
- I tried to build some non clustered indexes in the table for the field I was using to join. But timeout errors came out trying building them.
- I cannot partition the tables since I do not have SQL ENTERPRISE edition.
- Now, after another try, I stopped a too timeconsuming query and My database is "in recovery" mode since hours.. I guess I lost it and I have to start from the beginning. That is actually a good opportunity to try to build it more efficiently to have it usable.

Given this story, do you guys have any good practice to suggest or path I should follow in order to succeed launching join query? Or any explanation for what happened to my db?
Do you have any clues on how I should proceed? I am quite lost...

Thanks!

Francesco

Comment: you'd better to ask this question on DBA site. http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the size of the database?

Comment: The database is approximately around 250 Gb.

Answer (score 0):

1- If you are not using transactions in your code, remove the log file by making the database simple
2- In your queries avoid selecting all columns 
3- Avoid using subqueries or functions 
4- make indexes in your joining columns (preferred to be integers)
5- try to minimize the size of the columns based on your data and not use TEXT or NTEXT without a real need
6- If you can make some de-normalization (summary tables based on your joins) it will increase the performance and will not need joins.